# Consolidate __range and __startswith in Django model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I want to create a function that will provide the count of some data. But there are two scenarios occur:

1. Weekly email count - for this I am using **__range**
2. Today email count - for this I am using **__startswith**

my function looks like this:

```
def count_emails(from_date=None,to_date=None):
    emails = Emails.objects.all()
    if to_date is None:
        to_date = from_date
    count = emails.filter(initial_date__range=(from_date,to_date)).count()
    return count
```

Expectation:

```
def count_emails(from_date=None,to_date=None):
    emails = Emails.objects.all()
    if to_date is None:
        count = contact.filter(initial_date__stratswith=from_date).count()
    else:
       count = emails.filter(initial_date__range=(from_date,to_date)).count()
    return count
```

So for today email count, I am passing the only from_date but the count shows 0(zero) if I use `__startswith` instead of `__range` then the count will be correct.

So I need to make it into a single function and single variable.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

When you try set `to_date = from_date` you have empty range, but if your goal is one code line for any case, you can change range to `gte` and `lt`

```
def count_emails(from_date=None, to_date=None):
    emails = Emails.objects.all()
    if to_date is None:
        to_date = from_date
    to_date = to_date + timedelta(1)
    count = contact.filter(initial_date__gte=from_date, initial_date__lt=to_date)).count()
    return count
```

Comment: This will add 1 more day so the count becomes for two days?

Comment: yes, i was think, that initial data is `auto_now_add` field so it does not matter for today value how much will bу `to_date` value. now i change my answer hope it help you.

Comment: thanks. I saw timedelta and comes with a solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46069949/6695297

Answer (score 0):

I have tried one thing.

```
def count_emails(from_date=None, to_date=None):
    emails = Emails.objects.all()
    if to_date is None:
        from_date = datetime.datetime.combine(from_date, datetime.time.min)
        to_date = from_date + timedelta(hours=23, minutes=59)
    count = emails.filter(initial_date__range=(from_date, to_date))).count()
    return count
```

this helps me for both week and a single day

Comment: for your solution you can use more readable way: `to_date = datetime.datetime.combine(from_date, datetime.time.max)`

Comment: That makes no sense. `emails` is unused. `contact` undefined. Blows up if `to_date is` defined and `from_date` is not.